# Is possible to sending push notification to the existing GCM user from FCM?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the existing app that using GCM and have some issue with GCM reliability. I interested using FCM to replace the GCM, but I doubt about compatibility. I've some google search but still couldn't find a satisfactory answer, here some link:

[Migrating from gcm to fcm on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019331/migrating-from-gcm-to-fcm-on-android)

If FCM inherits from GCM, does FCM also support GCM token? Or we need to some config in the server  (using gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/ vs. fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/request in one server?)

I still doubt to migrating GCM to FCM, so I need some ideas from you all guys and I think send a notification from FCM console is not scalable for me because of too many notifications that triggered by user activities. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As much as I have understood from reading various documents and watching youtube recordings of 2016 I/O, FCM appears to be rebranded GCM. Server side integration will stay the same with option to switch endpoint domain name. When look a little closer you see that both domain names are referring to same IP address.

From client side integration much more has changes. FCM has a new SDK which makes certain things little easier to manage. Not sure if there are any improvements in terms of keeping app connected to the backend, listening incoming messages.