# Changing App Vendors: How to keep pushing to users

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are changing from an App vendor to a home-built App and we have tens of thousands of users opted in to push notifications in our Android App and this is the main way that users get into our App each day.

We have the tokens for the users from the current push vendor so we can migrate those into our push vendor, however the existing App is using our old App vendor's GCM (google cloud messaging) account from their Google Account.

I believe that if we setup our new App and push vendor configuration with our own GCM (or preferably FCM, firebase cloud messaging) account, then even with the push tokens we won't be able to reach the users in the new app until they open it and re-opt back in.  We'd like to avoid this since the existing users mostly come in via a push, so they will go dark once we update the App in the Play Store and can no longer push to them.

Is there a way to avoid this?  Perhaps a way to migrate them from the current GCM account to a new FCM account and preserving the ability to push to them without them having to open the App?  The App bundle Id and name and all that are staying the same and continue in our same Google Play Developer Console, it's only the GCM account that we want to change to our GCM/FCM account.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: I'm a little confused at what you're asking, but hopefully this helps. Firebase allows you to migrate from GCM pretty painlessly. Any GCM tokens in a Firebase server will still push out to those devices that are registered with a GCM client, allowing you time to update your client's implementation without worrying about backwards-compatibility.

Comment: My understanding is that we should import our GCM project as a FCM project in order to do this migration, but the GCM project is on another google account owned by the old App vendor and the FCM project that the new App will use is on our google account owned by us.

Comment: What I want is that when a user that today gets pushes from us using old App version and push vendor updates (perhaps in background) to our new App version once we release the new apk that we can then push from our new vendor and they will receive the push.  We will migrate the push tokens from the old vendor to our vendor, but my understanding is that Android still won't deliver the new push to them if the FCM app ID that we use in the new app and new push vendor is different from the FCM app id that was used when they opted in to our push in the first place.

Comment: You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) for the complete steps on how to migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging. Once you migrate your project from GCM to FCM, you'll be able to send like usual through FCM. Both GCM and FCM use InstanceID tokens so from the API or Firebase console there is no distinction between the clients. Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019331).