# Issue with endpoints when converting GCM app to FCM

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm converting my GCM app to FCM using [this guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).  My server code is written in C# running on an ASP.NET Web REST Service.  Existing code that does the post is as follows . . .

```
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.KeepAlive = false;
    Request.ContentType = "application/json";
    Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
    Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
```

In the "Update server endpoints" it says the old gcm endpoint of

> gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/

should be converted to

> fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/

However I have not been using that endpoint.  I have been using

> android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

very successfully for years.  I don't remember why I have /send.  Should I also append it to the new endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to have the older version. `android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` was more recent than `gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/` IIRC.

Either way, I would confirm that `android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` should be replaced with the `fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/` endpoint. (here's an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37517339/4625829) of mine for reference).