# How to send a push notification from web to android using firebase?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, push-notification

I want to send a push notification from the web app to the android mobile app users using firebase.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516589/send-push-notifications-from-server-with-fcm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your information if you want to send notification for testing purpose then you can use FCM console which provides you a way to pass **data** payload.

But in case your need you can have your own server too where you can pass your own **data** and **notification** payload

Refer following URL for more information

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref