# Is it possible to define push notifications for create-react-app (no back-end) triggered by the app's logic?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, push-notification

I have built a react application for notes with reminders.

You can see the code here:

https://github.com/YanivAf/NotesApp

Live version here:

https://corkboardnotes.netlify.app/

I want to make it more usable, by allowing push notifications that let users know there is a note's reminder, even if the user is not focused on the browser (and even better- when the browser is closed).

Searching on the web for a solution, I encountered [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/), but it seems that the notifications cannot be triggered from the code logic for webapps.

Is there a tool that can help me achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a native app, or is your react frontend hosted on a website?

I don't know rightaway if you needed to have a website-url, but for native apps (when using Firebase Cloud Messaging) you can send a post-request to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37517339/8941307).

If you're actually talking about a website, then you will need to add PWA capabilities to your react application. PWA's do support push-notifications, also on ios.

Comment: I do not have a native app. Do you have a recommended guide for adding PWA capabilities, specifically push-notifications?

Comment: I think [this video](https://youtu.be/dqreWfcJsV8) could help

Comment: Thanks! I'll research, but this seems to be the right direction :)